# Was there a Temporal Paradox in Men In Black III?

Tags: men-in-black-3

The main story thread of the movie [**Men in Black III**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_in_Black_3) involves going back in time using a Time Jump device to alter the past and save the earth's future.

I don't know much about time travel, and I know even less about [Temporal Paradoxes](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_paradox), but **was there a Temporal Paradox created in MIB<sup>3</sup>?** If so, then which?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this can be regarded as a temporal paradox, but there is indeed a kinda major plot issue.

When Agent J is fighting Boris The Animal in Cape Canaveral, he shouts "Heey! Boris The Animal!" in order to startle Boris. He then runs in Boris' direction, grabbing him before jumping from the top of the Saturn V launch pad. You can see this scene here:

When Agent J activates the time travel device, the scene makes it seem like Boris The Animal is also going back in time along with him. Moments later, they are both back at the top of the launch pad, but Agent J remembers jumping while Boris doesn't. This suggests that Boris died in the fall.

Now, if we just go along and assume that only Agent J goes back in time, there remains a larger problem. Up to that moment in the movie, we've seen that the time travel device transports someone back in time, but does not care if the person already existed in the "time of destination". So, when Agent J finds himself back at the top of the platform, there should be two of him: the one who just time-travelled, and the one who was there *before* the travel. That's not what happens.

You can try watching this video - but there's a chance you might end up more confused, instead of less, so I recommend you try to bear with my explanation first:

Upon some rationalization, I developed an hypothesis which *could* explain this strange feat. We notice that Agent J spawns at exactly the same place than his (seconds-)earlier self was... at the grips of Boris the Animal. Perhaps there is a "bug" in the time-travel device that causes a person to "collapse" (like a [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse)), should that happen. But this is just something I like to think about; it is not backed by the storywriters, as far as I know. As a bonus, this could also explain why he is not wound from the previous projectiles that Boris shoots at him.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly. As with almost every time travel movie, they make numerous small changes that probably ought to snowball into something greater, preventing the events of the movie, but the biggest change is that, by the end of the movie,

> Both Borises are dead by the end of the film, removing the entire reason to do the time traveling in the first place.

Ultimately, you pretty much just have to either turn your brain off, or wiggle your fingers and say, "self-healing timestream" until the paradoxes go away.